# Determine if your action was requested directly or redirected to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, redirect, http-referer

Say I'm on:

```
example.com/foo
```

I click on a button that goes to the `root_path`, typically it would be:

```
example.com/
```

In the controller action that receives the request it's determined that the user should be redirected to:

```
example.com/bar
```

In the controller action that receives that request I now wish to know if the user has been redirected via the `root_path`, so I check out the `request.referer`. But I discover that the referer is not `example.com/`, but `example.com/foo`.

I have inspected the `request` object, but it seems there is no trace of the paths a request have been redirected through. Is that correct, or is there a tell?

Here is the log:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-05-29 09:40:37 +0200
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {}
Redirected to https://example.com/bar
Completed 302 Found in 21ms

Started GET "/bar" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-05-29 09:40:37 +0200
Processing by BarController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {}
Completed 200 OK in 285ms (Views: 274.1ms)
```

I realise I could add a param when redirecting, but before that I want to make sure the informations are not already in the session.

Answer (score 1):

You can, for example, use [`flash`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html) to set some custom property like `:redirected_from`:

```rb
redirect_to '/foo', flash: { redirected_from: request.path }
```

Which you can later read in `example.com/bar` controller action

Comment: Interesting idea. How do I access it? IT doesn't seems like `request.flashes` exists.

Comment: Just `flash[:redirected_from]` inside a controller's action